# Macro log usage issue with static methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wrote macro that defines log level and prints out `TAG` + method name:

```
#define NSLogDebug(topic, frmt, ...) \
     do{ if(LOG_LEVEL >= 4) \
     NSLog( (topic @" : " @"%@" @" : "  frmt), \
    NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), ##__VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
```

Usage:

```
 #define TAG @"agent_magr"
 /* ... */     
-(void)registerforDeviceLockNotif
{
 NSLogDebug(TAG, @"init");
```

The output is:

```
Agent[741:907] agent_magr : registerforDeviceLockNotif : init
```

However it works only for non-static methods.

Into the method like:

```
static void displayStatusChanged(/*  */)
{}
```

I get error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier '_cmd' Did you mean 'rcmd'?
```

I thought to use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`:

```
#define NSLogDebug(topic, frmt, ...) \
     do{ if(LOG_LEVEL >= 4) \
     NSLog( (topic @" : " @"%s" @" : "  frmt), \
    __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ , ##__VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
```

but this one prints out full function with parameters:

```
Agent[773:907] agent_magr : void displayStatusChanged(CFNotificationCenterRef, void *, CFStringRef, const void *, CFDictionaryRef) : init
```

How can I make it work in static method?

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of `NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)` check with `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`

Comment: @MidhunMP  yes, see my question 2nd part. It prints out function with params

Comment: shameless self-advertisement: just use a decent logging framework and you don't have these problems: https://github.com/michaelpeternell/MPLog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a static method; it's a function. The `_cmd` variable only exists in methods (since only methods are called by selectors). If you want this to work in both functions and methods, you'll have to use either `__FUNCTION__` or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, which are both C strings.

Comment: It's actually a C function that's also static, as opposed to a class or instance method. Objective-C doesn't have static methods at all; what people call a static method in C++ is a class method in Objective-C, and behaves differently in some ways since it's still resolved at runtime. t know I'm splitting hairs here and not actually contradicting what you said, but there's a lot of terms to keep straight here and I'm hoping this is helpful to OP. :)

Comment: @StevenFisher thank you for good description. I'm not Obj-C programmer, just user and I looked for quick way to fix my problem without entering deeply. So i voted up both answers and accepted this one. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to solve this the same way `NSAssert` does. Namely, there's a `NSCAssert` that avoids using `_cmd` or `self`. Then you'll use `NSLogDebug` in Objective-C functions, and `NSCLogDebug` in C functions. I'd also advising not using the `NS` namespace here; you'll confuse yourself (or someone else reading the code) later.

Look in **NSException.h**:

```
#if !defined(_NSAssertBody)
#define NSAssert(condition, desc, ...)  \
    do {                \
    __PRAGMA_PUSH_NO_EXTRA_ARG_WARNINGS \
    if (!(condition)) {     \
        [[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInMethod:_cmd \
        object:self file:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] \
            lineNumber:__LINE__ description:(desc), ##__VA_ARGS__]; \
    }               \
        __PRAGMA_POP_NO_EXTRA_ARG_WARNINGS \
    } while(0)
#endif

#if !defined(_NSCAssertBody)
#define NSCAssert(condition, desc, ...) \
    do {                \
    __PRAGMA_PUSH_NO_EXTRA_ARG_WARNINGS \
    if (!(condition)) {     \
        [[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__] \
        file:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] \
            lineNumber:__LINE__ description:(desc), ##__VA_ARGS__]; \
    }               \
        __PRAGMA_POP_NO_EXTRA_ARG_WARNINGS \
    } while(0)
#endif
```